# Changes in Magento_Theme > layout are suddenly ignored (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, css

I have removed the CSS in `default_head_blocks.xml` successfully like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/test.css" />
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <remove src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <remove src="css/print.css" media="print" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Now I made some changes on CSS. After I turn all back as it was before it shows me Lumina CSS and it also ignores changes I made in `default.xml`. Before it works all, but now my changes in this Folder are ignored:

```
Theme > Magento_Theme > layout
```

I have no idea why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to solve the problem was duplicate the theme and give it a new name. Then use the new theme and it works.

Comment: I ran into the problem after migrating a shop to another webspace. I still don't know where the actual problem was but your workaround did it for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have been having exactly the same issue in Magento 2 Ver 2.2.4. However, for anyone arriving here having this problem, it is likely that your theme has a setting of 'virtual' in the database.

In the database, examine the 'theme' table, column 'type', if your theme it has a value of 1, the theme is 'virtual' and changes to your `default_head_blocks.xml` will be ignore. Change the setting to 0 clear the Magento 'var' folder and your changes should now be shown.

This solution can be [seen here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330#issuecomment-215537090).

Comment: This works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this same problem but I found it ridiculous to have to remove the theme and add it again. 
So my default.xml seemed to be ignored, so I renamed the layout folder to see if that would change anything; it broke everything. Okay, so the layout folder is read and used by Magento, why wouldn't the default? I emptied the file and started from scratch; all my changes were visible again!

TL;DR - there was a typo in a statement (a missing closing tag) somewhere in the file. Rather then give an error, it discarded everything in the file. So whenever somebody finds him/herself in this situation; empty the file and put everything back line by line 'till you see the error!